# Impossible to click button when nested lazy list scrolls in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have an issue where when a nested `LazyRow`/`LazyColumn` inside another scrollable view (such as a `Column` with the `vertical scroll` modifier) is scrolled, it causes an issue where it is not possible to click any button from the parent scrollable view.

At the code block below you can see an example of that issue.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(16.dp)
) {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(52.dp))

    Text(
        "Clicks: $clickCount",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.displayLarge,
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))

    //Not clickable when LazyRow or LazyColumn is scrolled
    Button(
        onClick = {
            clickCount += 1
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Button clicked")
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text("Click me")
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))

    //Not clickable when LazyRow or LazyColumn is scrolled
    Text(
        text = "Click me text",
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(50.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Blue)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures(
                    onTap = {
                        clickCount += 1
                    }
                )
            }
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

    //When this LazyRow is scrolled, the button click is not registered
    LazyRow {
        items(100) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Red)

            ) {
                Text("Item $it")
            }
        }
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))

    //When this LazyColumn is scrolled, the button click is not registered
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
    ) {
        items(100) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Red)

            ) {
                Text("Item $it")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried and didn't help:

1. replace `clickable` modifier on `pointerInput` modifier
2. move scrollStates to variables
3. use interaction sources of clickable elements

Comment: I found this question that appears to go into the same direction, maybe you find out what the actual problem is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74492356/click-event-during-scrolling-of-lazyrow-not-registered
For example, you could try to move the `verticalScroll` Modifier to the last position in the Modifier chain of the `Column`.

Comment: I tried to add `verticalScroll` modifier to the last position, but unfortunately, It didn't help. 
Of course, if i remove `verticalScroll` modifier altogether everything works fine, but I need this screen to be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

There are two open issues in the Google Issue Tracker that describes similar behaviour as your are observing:

[Issue #1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/289685606), [Issue #2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/319260186)

You can upvote the issues and leave a comment with your code to draw more attention to the problem.

Also check [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77788322/lazycolumn-cant-be-scrolled-vertically-if-theres-an-inner-lazyrow-which-is-cur). If there is a workaround for this bug, it will probably be posted there.